# Is there any way to tell elasticsearch standard tokenizer to don't consider $,@,# as delimiters?

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, delimiter

I am looking for a way which should not consider special characters like $,@,#,etc. as a delimiters by using standard tokenizer. it can be achievable by using whitespace tokenizer and word delimiter filter combination. but i am looking to use standard analyzer as i am not sure how it's generating tokens and to make use of other benefits of standard tokenizer.

if there is no way to do this with standard tokenizer. please give me some suggestions how token generation happening internally and what are other benefits with standard tokenizer.

--Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use uax_url_email tokenizer. here is the description for this,

```
    UAX URL Email Tokenizer
    The uax_url_email tokenizer is like the standard tokenizer
 except that it recognises URLs and email addresses as single tokens.
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html